# Github showing file in "File changed" list although the file is identical on these branches

Tags: git, github

From master I made branch `service` and made some changes then I went back to master and created branch `service2` on which I pushed half of changes from `service`.

Now on github I'm creating pull request service <- service2.

In PR in "File changed" list at GH I see file which is identical and have same timestamp.

[image]

to make sure this file is same at `service` and `service2` I executed following command in powershell

[image]

I'm confused why this file appears as added file. I want to see only differences between service and service2 to see like: what left do I need to add to service2 to make it same as service (debugging issue).

---

Also command `git diff service service2 -- src` doesn't show addonsStore.js is modified between this two branches so git is woking fine just dunno why it shows as changed on github :(.

Comment: *on which I pushed half of changes from service* did this include the file in question?

Comment: Yes of course. You can see this file on screenshot of powershell.

Comment: Tell me about your line ending configuration.  Do you have a `.gitattributes`?  What is it?

Comment: Both files have LF as line ending. I mean they have empty line at the end. I don't hany `.gitattributes` file. Interesting is that `git diff service service2 -- src` doesn't show addonsStore.js is modified. So it's like github issue or I'm missing something. I'll edit post with this info.

Comment: “then I went back to master and created branch service2” So service and service2 emanate from two different points in master? “branch service2 on which I pushed half of changes from service” You did what, exactly?

Comment: To be more clear I made `service` and `service2` from another branch which was and is still same. So no - service and service2 are not made from two different point they are made from exactly same codebase. On `service` i changed few files and added 2 more files. I just copied this two files and added them to `service2` manually. So currently I expect to see only changes from files in PR.